# INNER JOIN on three tables with condition

Tags: php, mysql, inner-join

I am trying to fetch all the photos detail from a tag slug *(URL for the tag)*, the database has three tables:

```
|-----------------------|
|==> photo              |
|   -> id               |
|   -> custom_id        |
|   -> title            |
|-----------------------|
|==> tags               |
|   -> id               |
|   -> slug             |
|-----------------------|
|==> tags_relation      |
|   -> tid              | <-- this is the tags.id
|   -> pid              | <-- this is the photo.custom_id
|-----------------------|
```

here is my mysql code to INNER JOIN all the tables and to get 20 photos from a tag:

```
SELECT photo.*, tags.*, tags_relation.*, 
FROM tags WHERE tags.slug = 'people' 
INNER JOIN tags_relation ON = tags_relation.tid = tags.id 
INNER JOIN photo ON photo.custom_id = tags_relation.pid
LIMIT 20  
ORDER BY photo.date DESC
```

The query is not correct anyway, and i can't understand how the INNER JOIN should work here, any idea?
Thanks

Comment: I think you had an error within first line its `tgas.*` instead of `tags.*` and within second line its `FORM` instead of `FROM`

Comment: @NarendraSisodia thanks for pointing that, it was some typo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL has a specific ordering of clauses.  In your case:

- SELECT
- FROM
- WHERE
- GROUP BY
- ORDER BY
- LIMIT

This is *always* the ordering within a query.  Note that `JOIN` expressions are not "clauses".  They are part of the `FROM` clause (and in MySQL, the `update` and `delete` clauses as well).

Applied to your query:

```
SELECT p.*, t.*, tr.*
FROM tags t INNER JOIN
     tags_relation tr
     ON tr.tid = t.id INNER JOIN
     photo p
     ON p.custom_id = tr.pid
WHERE t.slug = 'people' 
ORDER BY p.date DESC
LIMIT 20
```

You will note that the indentation highlights the clauses which are a fundamental part of the language.

I also added table aliases, which make the query easier to write and to read.  And fixed some minor things, such as misplaced commas.

I note you are pulling too many columns out of the data.  You should just list the columns you want (probably `p.*`).

Comment: They might not be clauses, but for me treating them as such aids readability. I prefer my formatting to yours (obviously) but each to their own.

Comment: @GordonLinoff i have learned many things from your answer, thankyou so much. One more thing i don't get the idea you pointed at the last line of your answer.

Comment: @meh . . . There is probably no reason to put the tag in the `select`, because you already know it is `'slug'`.

Comment: I am facing another problem is that the title, slug column of 'photo' table is being replaced by the title, slug column of 'tags' table! can't understand how to make them seperate, can you help? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
SELECT photo.*, tags.*, tags_relation.* 
    FROM tags WHERE tags.slug = 'people' 
    INNER JOIN tags_relation ON(tags_relation.tid = tags.id) 
    INNER JOIN photo ON (photo.custom_id = tags_relation.pid)
    ORDER BY photo.date DESC
    LIMIT 20
```